# Average county(fips) precipitation and remove stationID with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, dplyr

Sample Dataset : https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3l2uub1cttwmf2/test.csv?dl=0

What I need to do is get the average APPT for each fips code by year, and then reduce it down to just 1 observation for each fips code.  This should give me the average APPT(average precipitation per year) for each fips code.  The gridNumber variable is a station ID located within the county, so by averaging these I should get 1 average precipitation for fips code.

I'm trying to do this with dplyr, but anything will do.  This is a small sample of a rather large dataset that includes all counties in the U.S.

Here's what I've tried :

```
df3 <- test %>%
     group_by(fips, Year) %>%
     summarize(ppt = mean(APPT))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmmmm.  I need to take each unique fips code, get mean(APPT) for each fips code, and then drop it to 1 observation for each fips code.  Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, this is time series data, so there is a year for each fips code also.

Comment: It seems to drop down to 1 observation for each fips code per year for the example data

Comment: @akrun Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I am only getting that result with `df3` with `34` rows

Comment: @akrun When I run the command I used it only gives me 1 observation and 1 variable, which I assume is just the total mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you must have loaded `plyr` also.  Please check the [`dplyr issue`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/347).  One way would be to do this on a fresh R console or detach `plyr` or even `dplyr::summarize` would be helpful.  `plyr` also has `summarize` function so it is possible that the function was using `plyr::summarize`.

```
df3 <- test %>%
            group_by(fips, Year) %>%
            dplyr::summarize(ppt = mean(APPT))
```

Having said that, I would advise not to use `summarise` for multiple groups because

```
 test %>%
      group_by(fips, Year) %>% 
      summarize(ppt=mean(APPT))
 #Source: local data frame [34 x 3]
 #Groups: fips #omitted the last 'Year`
```

Though, the results would be the same, a recent post (don't have the link) suggested difference in result between this and other grouping functions.  If speed is a concern, you can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, list(ppt=mean(APPT)), by=list(fips, Year)]
```

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(APPT~fips+Year, test, mean)
```

Comment: Ahhhh I see what's going on.  I thought summarize and summarise was the difference between the packages?

Comment: @Amstell If you check `?summarise` or `?summarize` you will have both `dplyr` and `plyr` options.  I think the `s` `z` is not that important

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'm glad you put up the `data.table` example as I think I need to start using that more instead of dplyr.  Thanks for your help!